# No params being posted to Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, parameters

I have a form in an app with some nested fields. 
I'm using `simple_form_for`, bootstrap, slim and Rails 4.2 and a form backing object as described [here](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit)

Here's the proof params are missing on the server side (N.B. I have checked the `authenticity_token` field is in the markup)

## This is the log

```
Started POST "/example_sentences/9/breakdowns" for ::1 at 2015-08-31 12:37:57 +0900
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (18.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by BreakdownsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"example_sentence_id"=>"9"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Switching off CSRF protection to try and debug gives this:

```
Started POST "/example_sentences/9/breakdowns" for ::1 at 2015-08-31 13:00:05 +0900
Processing by BreakdownsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"example_sentence_id"=>"9"}
  User Load (24.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 355ms (ActiveRecord: 156.3ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: breakdown:
```

Obviously, there's quite a number of factors that mean this is deviating from the Rails way, so any number of things could be going wrong. And showing the view code would introduce a lot more questions.

So, I'll show the generated HTML (minus styling info) and ask if anyone can see anything clearly wrong with this. I'm kind of hoping it will be a facepalm moment and missing something obvious.

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" id="new_breakdown" action="/example_sentences/9/breakdowns" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="cOU87EZXRkV1a0QA1ohwlqM5Ny43QvgcRaqKan9mdgs12jR8RnJfyVXp9VIJHkMRkBUvZ16Io7QaGcBazjVqGw==">
  <input type="text" value="これ" name="breakdown[word_mapping][1][text]" id="breakdown_word_mapping_1_text" >
  <input type="text" value="this" name="breakdown[word_mapping][1][translation]" id="breakdown_word_mapping_1_translation">
  <input type="text" value="は" name="breakdown[word_mapping][2][text]" id="breakdown_word_mapping_2_text">
  <input type="text" value="" name="breakdown[word_mapping][2][translation]" id="breakdown_word_mapping_2_translation">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save translations">
</form>
```

### Additional info

In ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb

during the `:valid_authenticity_token?` check line 277

For request.body.read I can see the authenticity token
    "utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=RTFWCJZ3QnRgnNWFF66ej2aetx7H5n7BcbLKW4v145YADl6YllJb%2BEAeZNfIOK0IVbKvV64sJWkuAYBrOqb%2Fhg%3D%3D&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B1%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B1%5D%5Btranslation%5D=this&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B1%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B1%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B2%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%81%AF&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B2%5D%5Btranslation%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B2%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B2%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B3%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%83%9A%E3%83%B3&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B3%5D%5Btranslation%5D=pen&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B3%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B3%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B4%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B4%5D%5Btranslation%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B4%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B4%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btranslation%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%81%AF&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btranslation%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%83%9A%E3%83%B3&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btranslation%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btext%5D=%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Btranslation%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5Breading%5D=&breakdown%5Bword_mapping%5D%5B%5D%5B_destroy%5D=0&commit=Save+translations"

But the value of `encoded_masked_token` is `nil`

In fact the `path_parameters` is the only part of the params I'm getting in the request.

```
in: "~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb"

(byebug) pp @env.keys.sort.grep(/action_dispatch/).grep(/param/).map{|k| [k, @env[k]]}

[["action_dispatch.parameter_filter", [:password]],
 ["action_dispatch.request.parameters",
  {"controller"=>"breakdowns",
   "action"=>"create",
   "example_sentence_id"=>"9"}],
 ["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters",
  {:controller=>"breakdowns", :action=>"create", :example_sentence_id=>"9"}],
 ["action_dispatch.request.query_parameters", {}],
 ["action_dispatch.request.request_parameters", {}]]
```

So I'm somehow losing the params already.

Comment: show your controller codes

Comment: So I wanted to avoid discussing too much about the controller or view, as the params themselves are not even hitting the controller. As you can see I get the example_sentence_id param from the url but nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the problem was with the format of the name param. I didn't catch where exactly in the Rails stack all the params including the authenticity_token/CSRF token get lost but basically:

Instead of this:
`breakdown[word_mapping][0][translation]`

This is correct:
`breakdown[word_mappings_attributes][0][translation]`

It's possibly worth adding extra info in case anyone else had a similar issue.

I was using a nested form with a form-backing object as described in the pivotal blog post linked in the OP.

My slim code looked like this, based on an out-of-date recommendation elsewhere:

```
= f.simple_fields_for "word_mapping[]", @breakdown.word_mappings do |w|
  = render "word_mapping_fields", f: w
```

which was resulting in the output HTML shown in the post.

The correct version is:

```
= f.simple_fields_for "word_mappings", @breakdown.word_mappings do |w|
  = render "word_mapping_fields", f: w
```

On my form-backing object I had to delegate, `word_mappings_attributes=` to the `AR` object `ExampleSentence` in this case. Although using `delegate` itself didn't work so I had to manually write the code.

```
def word_mappings_attributes=(attrs)
  example_sentence.word_mappings_attributes=attrs
end
```

I also had to add the following to the form:

```
class << self
  delegate :reflect_on_association, to: ExampleSentence
end
```

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it sounds like your code to require your parameters is incorrect.

If you have something like the following:

```
params.require(breakdown: [fields])
```

Then it should be

```
params.require(:breakdown).permit(fields)
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too, but as you can see the params are not hitting the controller. Even the CSRF token is not being found

Comment: OK, so you might have invalid HTML in your form that is closing off the form before your attributes are included. Can you add the complete form (including "styling elements") to the question?

Comment: Thanks.I just added info that shows the body of the request. Also this is generated via slim, so missing closing tags wouldn't be possible. Obviously I can add in controller/view code etc but it seems like a distraction as the error seems to be happening somewhere in the Rails stack before hitting my code